# Running remote selenium tests throws error: '[testng] Unknown option: -sourcedir'

Tags: ant, selenium, vmware, jenkins, testng

I have a cluster of VM's (all Windows 7) that I am trying to use to run some continuous integration from Jenkins. The tests are written in Java and from my local environment (windows 7) I can remotely connect to a VM and run my tests without any problems.

When I schedule the tests to run in Jenkins, I use the same command line arguments but during execution I get:

...

```
start-server:

doTest:
   [testng] Usage: <main class> [options]
   [testng]  The XML suite files to run
   [testng] Unknown option: -sourcedir
   [testng]   Options:
   [testng]     -configfailurepolicy               Configuration failure policy (skip or
   [testng]                                        continue)
   [testng]     -d                                 Output directory
   [testng]     -dataproviderthreadcount           Number of threads to use when running
   [testng]                                        data providers
   [testng]     -excludegroups                     Comma-separated list of group names to 
   [testng]                                        exclude
   [testng]     -groups                            Comma-separated list of group names to be
   [testng]                                        run
   [testng]     -junit                             JUnit mode
   [testng]                                        Default: false
   [testng]     -listener                          List of .class files or list of class
   [testng]                                        names implementing ITestListener or
   [testng]                                        ISuiteListener
   [testng]     -methods                           Comma separated of test methods
   [testng]                                        Default: []
   [testng]     -methodselectors                   List of .class files or list of class
   [testng]                                        names implementing IMethodSelector
   [testng]     -objectfactory                     List of .class files or list of class
   [testng]                                        names implementing ITestRunnerFactory
   [testng]     -parallel                          Parallel mode (methods, tests or classes)
   [testng]     -port                              The port
   [testng]     -reporter                          Extended configuration for custom report
   [testng]                                        listener
   [testng]     -suitename                         Default name of test suite, if not
   [testng]                                        specified in suite definition file or
   [testng]                                        source code
   [testng]     -suitethreadpoolsize               Size of the thread pool to use to run
   [testng]                                        suites
   [testng]                                        Default: 1
   [testng]     -testclass                         The list of test classes
   [testng]     -testjar                           A jar file containing the tests
   [testng]     -testname                          Default name of test, if not specified in
   [testng]                                        suitedefinition file or source code
   [testng]     -testnames                         The list of test names to run
   [testng]     -testrunfactory, -testRunFactory   The factory used to create tests
   [testng]     -threadcount                       Number of threads to use when running
   [testng]                                        tests in parallel
   [testng]     -usedefaultlisteners               Whether to use the default listeners
   [testng]                                        Default: true
   [testng]     -log, -verbose                     Level of verbosity
   [testng]
```

stop-server:
[selenium-shutdown] Getting: http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDown
[selenium-shutdown] To: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HomePage/workspace/result.txt
[selenium-shutdown] DGF Errors during shutdown are expected

My Jenkins instance runs on a different box (ubuntu). I just upgraded to Ant 1.8.2 on that box. Can this be a testng issue? I've seen this issue a few places but no concrete answers yet, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, Jenkins is passing "-sourcedir" to TestNG, which is not a recognized option.

Comment: The problem is, that -sourcedir is a KNOWN option. (http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml). But it is SHOWN as unknown - that is the problem.